# Copying SQL Server Data to another Database on another Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed a SQL Server database on my customer's server.

I have an exact duplicate database schema on my laptop to enable me to work on things whilst I am off site.

However I need to copy the actual data in the customers database into my copy on the laptop, in order to test a few things.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

The customer server and my laptop are not connected (although I have VPN access to the customer's server) so I do not believe I can do this with TSQL.

Is there a way to Export from SSMS and then Import into my laptop database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Backaup` your database and then `restore` on another server.

From MSDN:

> **RESTORE** If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE.
>   If the database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information
>   is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role
>   membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and
>   undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed,
>   members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE
>   permissions.

Comment: Doing this gives me an do not have permissions message when I attempt to restore.  It seems SQL Server will not allow me to restore from a backup created on another Server.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation, what I do is I take the customer database offline (detach), copy the file off to my laptop and re-attach the database back to the customer server.

Uses SSMs and right click the database and click detach. Be sure, no one is actively working on the database. Also be sure that you know the location of the mdf file and you have access to it. Once detached, copy the file off. Then go the SSMS, right-click on 'database' and select 'attach'. Select the mdf file again and you get the database back on the customer's server.

You can attach the mdf file you copied in the steps above into your own server instance.

The otherway will be taking a backup and restoring on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to setup data repication.
See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

since you've mentioned that you can be connected through VPN, you can possibly copy the data from one server into another using `INSERT INTO...SELECT`, eg

```
INSERT INTO server2.database.dbo.tableName (col1, ..., colN)
SELECT col1, ..., colN
FROM server2.database.dbo.tableNam
```

or use `Backup and Restore` feature in SSMS

- [Backing Up and Restoring How-to Topics (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189621%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Generate Script` task:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/

You can also copy all database with `Copy Databse`:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1792/upgrading-to-sql-server-2008-using-copy-database-wizard/

or `Export data`:

http://blog.winhost.com/exporting-sql-server-data-with-import-and-export-wizard/